# Streaming with different audio and video sources

Tags: youtube, streaming, jwplayer, flowplayer

Youtube separate the audio and video(DASH) for 480p quality and above.I want to know how do they stream the video if the audio is not part of the video.Is there any player that has a similar feature that allow streaming for a video that has a different link for the audio

Answer (score 2):

The DASH manifest file (.mpd) contains information about the individual audio and video streams for a particular video stream (the terminology gets a bit confusing as when you 'stream' a video packaged in DASH format it actually typically contains multiple individual audio and video streams).

The audio and video streams can be referenced in different ways, but one common way is that a URL is provided.

Video is often provided in multiple bit rate streams to allow for different network conditions, but the audio is often small enough that a single stream is ok for most network conditions. For this reason having a single audio stream that can play with multiple bit rate video streams is important.

Similarly, different language audio streams may be included in the manifest so the player/user can select whichever one is appropriate.

Any player that can play DASH format should be able to handle playing streams with different URLs (links) to the individual video and audio links.

Comment: Can you show me an example of an html5/flash player that stream dash

Comment: @user2650277 - BitMovin's BitDASH player (https://www.dash-player.com) and Google Shaka player (http://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com) are HTML5 players that play DASH streams. Unified Streaming's packager (http://www.unified-streaming.com/products/packager/) is an example of a server side packager that can produce a DASH stream. There are also various open source DASH streamers/packagers, some VLC based and this one, edash: https://github.com/google/edash-packager/blob/master/README.md